# How to install a specific nvidia driver on linux mint?

Tags: linux-mint

Am thinking about switching from windows 10 to Linux mint, but when I have searched for driver updates.. I saw that I can't install a specific driver because i got scammed i bought a non-official nvidia graphic card.. I used to install drivers manually because when I use softwares like driver booster, etc. it installs the wrong driver the resolution proportion isn't very well.. brightness issues etc... so can I install a specific driver on Linux mint?

Comment: Welcome, could you add the output of `sudo lshw -C video`. Please.

Answer (score 0):

Mint install the official Nvidia drivers at installation time, if you check the box 'Instal 3th party drivers'.

Comment: so if i check the insall 3th party driver .. i'll be able to install the driver that i download from nvidia website ?

Comment: The installer will selecty the appropriate driver following your hardware.

And there is an entry in the menu :  
   'Gestionnaire de pilotes (' Drivers handling'  ?)  
You can check that after install.